# TTNavigator not pushing onto navigation stack

Tags: ios, three20

I am using the TTTableView class from the Three20 framework to create table view cells with styled content, including HTML with URLs. The cells look and work almost fine. The URL are picked up, and tapping on one of the fire the appropriate delegate method. However, the URL is open in a TTWebController the TTWebController does not have a back arrow to pop the view of the navigation stack.

Heres my code:

```
TTTableStyledTextItem *messageItem = [TTTableStyledTextItem itemWithText:[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:message lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES]];
messageItem.delegate = self;

TTListDataSource *dataSource = [[TTListDataSource alloc] init];
[dataSource.items addObject:messageItem];

TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.delegate = self;
navigator.window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;

TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];


self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

The URLs are highlighted in the cells and tapping one fires this method:

```
- (BOOL)navigator: (TTBaseNavigator *)navigator shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *) URL {
return YES;
```

}

The TTWebController does not seem to be pushed onto the navigation stack, it is just "shown" without a back arrow. Any thoughts?

**Update with my solution**
After playing around some more I think the problem is is that I am trying to use the Three20 URL navigation method to push a new view controller while at the same time using a regular iOS UINavigationController. The point at which the TTWebcontroller is being shown is the first view controller on the Three20 navigation stack, and as such is the root view controller and so does not have any notion of "going back" to a previous view.

Here is my work around:

```
- (BOOL)navigator: (TTBaseNavigator *)navigator shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *) URL {
    // setup a webcontroller with the URL and push it
    TTWebController *webController = [[TTWebController alloc] init];
    [webController openURL:URL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];
    [webController release];

    // dont navigate with TTBaseNavigator
    // this does not use the regular UINavigation stack and
    // ... the new view becomes rootview and has no back button
    return NO;
}
```

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

That might happen depending on how you presented the viewController containing the tableView. It that viewController pushed onto a UINavigationController or invoked per url (in that case Three20 would automatically create a navigationController for you).

You need to make sure, that a navigationController onto with the WebController can be pushed exists.

Comment: The view controller containing the table view is pushed onto a regular UINavigationControler and it is the top most view controller in the code example I gave. I would have thought that the WebController bring invoked would also get pushed. Do I need to specifically give the WebController or the TTNavigator a reference to the UINavigationControllr being used?

Comment: No, that would normally not be the case, but might be worth a try. Use `setRootViewController:` on `TTNavigator`.

Comment: Not sure I am going to get any more comments here so thanks for your input tonklon. I think I am going to try creating the view that pushes the TTWebController using the Three20 TTNavigator approach. That might solve the problem by creating the view hierarchy beforehand.